# How to remove outliers from each group within a boxplot?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am wanting to remove all the outliers for each individual ID in a boxplot. I have tried the following code:

'''

```
    AB_Q1 = combine['AB_MEAN'].quantile(0.25)
    AB_Q3 = combine['AB_MEAN'].quantile(0.75)
    AB_IQR = AB_Q3 - AB_Q1

    AB_filter = (combine['AB_MEAN'] >= (AB_Q1 - 1.5 * AB_IQR)) & (combine['AB_MEAN'] <= (AB_Q3 + 1.5 * AB_IQR))
    AB_remove = combine.loc[AB_filter]

    combine.drop(combine.loc[AB_filter].index, inplace=True)

    AB = sns.boxplot(x=combine['FEEDER'], y=combine['AB_MEAN'], hue='FEEDER', data = combine)
```

'''

This worked for removing all the outliers for the particular column of data but removed too much needed information.

The first images is similar to the original data plot before the data was removed.
[image]

The next image shows what happened after the data was removed.
[image]

As seen in the first image there are 6 unique identifiers with 4500+ rows of data apiece.